# Trying to make every image on page spin for Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to figure out how to make my javascript find every img tag on a page and then animate it to make it continuously spin? So far I've only created a variable to find every img tag:

```
var DI= document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**edit**: Just to clarify, this is for a chrome extension I'm making, so it would have to inject itself into preexisting websites.

**edit 2**: Ok, so I understand CSS animations would be the easiest way to do this. But, how do I make the connection between finding all the image tags on a web page via Javascript to the actual CSS animation itself (so that it will find all images then make aforementioned images spin)?

Comment: How do you want to make the images spin? CSS3 animations?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this?

Comment: It's *possible* to do what you want in JavaScript. It's also more complicated and vastly less efficient than doing it with a CSS animation.

Comment: Yes, I think CSS could work... This is actually for a chrome extension I'm making so it is supposed to be injected on every web page you're on, so I just thought that maybe it would be easier if it was all on the same content.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for javascript.
You can use CSS animations for this.

Create a keyframed animation named `spin`

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Style your image tags using this animation and loop it infinite.

```
img {
    animation: 2000ms spin infinite linear;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odpyq1eq/3/)**

If you don't want every single `img` tag in your website to rotate, but in stead want it only on a specific page, style a class with these settings in stead of the direct `img` element.

EDIT:

If you want to initiate the spinning via javascript in stead of applying the style directly to all images in the CSS, style a class and add that class via javascript.

CSS

```
.spinning {
    animation: 2000ms spin infinite linear;
}
```

Javascript

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i){
    imgs[i].className += " spinning";
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odpyq1eq/4/)**

Comment: Sorry I was being so grossly unclear! I'm not making a website; this is actually for a Chrome extension so it would have to be injected into a preexisting web page.

Comment: @ooohfff So, you can use CSS, but only when you inject it via javascript, is that it?

Comment: @ooohfff chrome content-scripts support injecting CSS files as well. See - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Right. I guess my real question is: How do I make the connection between finding all the image tags on a web page via Javascript to the actual CSS animation itself (so that it will find all images  _then_ make aforementioned images spin)?

Comment: @ooohfff there is no need to explicitly find all the images using JS, as the CSS will be applied to all images. If you want to delay the effect, and initiate it with javascript, then you can apply a special class `.spinning` to the images using JS, and then target that class with the CSS `img.spinning {etc..}`.

Comment: @ooohfff I've updated the answer with a little snippet that let's you add a class with this animation to all images via javascript

Comment: @timo Thanks for all the help! You're right, it works with just the CSS :)